# How does the garuDa purANa extol Lord Shiva as supreme almighty?

Tags: shiva, garuda-purana

I think in the 16th.chapter of garuDa purANa. There are verses which talk about Sri Shiva as supreme being.

Can.someone please give insight on this?

Comment: What is the problem if it does so?

Comment: i think you want those verses to read. :)

Comment: @Fiercelord yes that would be nice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

okay i found the verses you were searching:—
**CHAPTER XVI**
**An Account of the Law for Liberation.**

> 1-4. Garuḍa said: I have heard fromyou, O Ocean of compassion, about
>   the transmigrating of the individual, through ignorance, in the worlds
>   of change. I now wish to hear about the means for eternal liberation.O
>   Lord, O Ruler of the Shining Ones, compassionate to those who seek
>   refuge,--in this terrible world of change, in the unsubstantial, in
>   all deep miseries,The endless multitudes of individuals, placed in
>   various kinds of bodies, are born and die--of them no end is
>   known.Always miserable in this world, no one is ever known to be
>   happy. O Lord of Liberation, tell me by what means they may obtain
>   release, O Lord.
>
> 5-7. The Blessed Lord said: Listen, O Tārkṣya, and I will explain to
>   you what you have asked, even by the hearing of which a man is
>   released from the world of change.**There is a Shining One, Śiva, who
>   has the nature of Supreme Brāhmaṇ, who is partless, all-knowing,
>   all-doing, Lord of all, stainless and secondless,Self-illumined,
>   beginningless and endless, beyond the Beyond, without attributes,
>   Being and Knowing and Bliss.** That which is considered the individual
>   is from a part of Him.
>
> 8-10 These, like sparks of a fire, with beginningless ignorance,
>   separated and encased in bodies bybeginningless karma,Are fettered by
>   forms of good and evil, giving happiness and misery,--with nationality
>   of body, length of life, and fortune born of karma.In every life
>   obtained. They have also, O Bird, a higher and more subtle body,
>   theliṅga, lasting until liberation.

link:— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/gpu18.htm

**I think this is what you were searching for :)**

Comment: mention not friend ;)