# Do any Vaishnavite Puranas glorify Siva in places?

Tags: shiva, puranas, vaishnavism

For example, Varaha Purana

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sathvishayam/UuQQF62dwwU

> To cap it all, Chapter 58 (Saubhagya Vrata) corroborates this point unequivocally - we have seen this already.
>
> yA shrIH sA girijA proktA yo hariH sa trilocanaH || 3 ||
>   evaM sarveShu shAstreShu purANeShu ca gadyate |
>
> etasmAd anyathA yastu brute shAstraM pRRithak tayA || 4 ||
>   rudro janAnAM martyAnAM kAvyaM shAstraM na tad bhavet |
>
> viShNuM rudra kRRitaM brUyAc ChrIr gaurIti nigadyate || 5 ||
>   etayor antaraM brUyAt so .adhametyucyate janaiH |
>
> taM nAstikaM vijAnIyAt sarva-dharma bahiShkRRitam || 6 ||
>   Meaning: Lakshmi is identical with Girija and Hari is identical with three-eyed Rudra. It is so declared in all Shastras and Puranas. Any Shastra or Kavya which states otherwise is not worthy of its name. Vishnu should be considered as Rudra and Lakshmi as Gauri. He who speaks of difference between them is lowly (Adhama) among people and should be considered an atheist outside the field of Dharma.)

'

Comment: Garuda Puran ([here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/22365/how-does-the-garuda-purana-extol-lord-shiva-as-supreme-almighty) )also says somewhat similar, you can add. But It isn'tt necessary all Purans should say & also other verses in the same texts can make discrepancies saying contrary things

Answer (score 5):

The Srimad Bhagavatam, a principle Vaishnavite Purana, glorifies Lord Shiva in the seventh chapter of the eighth canto:

> The prajāpatis said: **O greatest of all Devas, Mahādeva, Supersoul of all living entities and cause of their happiness and prosperity, we have come to the shelter of your lotus feet.** Now please save us from this fiery poison, which is spreading all over the three worlds. (Srimad Bhagavatam 8.7.21)
>
> **O Lord, you are the cause of bondage and liberation of the entire universe because you are its ruler. Those who are advanced in spiritual consciousness surrender unto you, and therefore you are the cause of mitigating their distresses, and you are also the cause of their liberation. We therefore worship Your Lordship.** (Srimad Bhagavatam 8.7.22)
>
> **O Lord, you are self-effulgent and supreme. You create this material world by your personal energy, and you assume the names Brahmā, Viṣṇu and Maheśvara when you act in creation, maintenance and annihilation.** (Srimad Bhagavatam 8.7.23)

[This](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/gpu/gpu18.htm) chapter of the Garuda Purana, which is another Vaishnavite Purana, also glorifies Lord Shiva:

> The Blessed Lord (Vishnu) said: Listen, O Tārkṣya, and I will explain to you what you have asked, even by the hearing of which a man is released from the world of change. **There is a Shining One, Śiva, who has the nature of Supreme Brāhmaṇ, who is partless, all-knowing, all-doing, Lord of all, stainless and secondless, Self-illumined, beginningless and endless, beyond the Beyond, without attributes, Being and Knowing and Bliss.** That which is considered the individual is from a part of Him.

Comment: You can also add the verses from the link I have pasted below the question if interested.